# TypeError: 'Module' object is not callable Help please

Tags: python

Got this weird error
can anyone help?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 172, in <module>
    main()
  File "./test.py", line 150, in main
    if random() < .5 and losttwice < 5:
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable


import urllib2,urllib,os,simplejson, random
```

Comment: Technically that link refers to `socket`, but it's the same cause. You could replace the word `socket` with random and they would be the same answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `random.random()` not just `random`. `random` is a module that contains functions like `random`, `randint` etc:

```
>>> import random
>>> random.random()
0.376462621569017
```

help on `random.random`:

```
random(...)
    random() -> x in the interval [0, 1).
```

If you only want to use the `random()` function from `random`` module, then you can also do:

```
>>> from random import random  #imports only random() from random module
>>> random()                   #now use random() directly,
0.7979255998231091
```

Comment: I'm using this if random() < .5 as 50% chance wil random.random() will offer the same function?

Comment: `help(random.random)`. yes.

Comment: @Mark Glad that helped. :) Feel free to [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) when the system allows you.

Comment: In 2022 the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/random.html#examples) clearly say call it like `random()` and still I had to search for this answer, which solves the problem. it doesn't properly show how to import anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

`random` is the name of a module; `random.random` is a function in that module. So you want to do `random.random() < .5`, not `random() < .5`.

Comment: which is always true... people should be banned from upvoting.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: Sorry, that was actually a typo (the question uses `.5`).

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to call the `random` module. Try calling one of the functions in it instead, such as `random.choice()`.